# Saving an updated number with user default, after using Callback

Tags: ios, swift, callback, nsuserdefaults

In my budgeting app, I have some `UserDefaults` saved. From the users profile, they can click a button that lets them put in how much money they spent today. I segue from the **UserInfoVC** screen, to an **AddSubtractMoneyVC** screen (which is simply a calculator) where they enter a number such as "32" and click submit. Then I use a callback to pass back the amount *(what number they entered subtracted from their daily budget default)* to give them an updated daily budget.

I need for every time a new amount gets sent back through the callback- that this new amount is saved, so that the next time they add money, it subtracts from the newest amount and not the previous user default.

**QUESTION**: Should I set a new `UserDefault` after I get their new number, or how exactly do i do this?

Sorry I'm very new to Swift, so small things take me a while to get. This may be a simple fix, but I've been trying all day, thanks.

In the **UserInfoViewController** - I segue to the *"addMoneyButton"*

In the **AddSubtractMoneyVC** i have a function *sendBackUpdatedNumber*, which is use to subtract the number they added from the original daily budget they had. I need to figure out how to store this new number so that overtime they add money, they are subtracting from the latest number.

```
class UserInfoViewController : ViewController {

    var userNamePassedOver : String?
    var userDailyBudgetPassedOver : Double?
    var userDailySavingsPassedOver : Double?
    var userMonthlyEarningsPassedOver : Double?
    var userDesiredSavingsPassedOver : Double?
    var newAmountPassedBack : Double = 0.0

    let monthlyPay = "monthlyPay"
    let name = "name"
    var dailySavingsDefault = "dailySavingsDefault"
    var dailyBudgetDefault = "dailyBudgetDefault"

    var newSavingsDefault : Double?
    let newUserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    @IBOutlet weak var progressToGoal: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dailySavingsNumberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dailySpendingLimitLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let name = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: name) as? String{
            userNameLabel.text = name
        }

        if let monthlyPay = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKeyPath: monthlyPay) as? String{
            progressToGoal.text = monthlyPay
        }

        if let dailySavingsDefault = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: dailySavingsDefault) as? Double{

          dailySavingsNumberLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", dailySavingsDefault)
            userDailySavingsPassedOver = dailySavingsDefault
        }

       if let dailyBudgetDefault = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: dailyBudgetDefault) as? Double{

         dailySpendingLimitLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", dailyBudgetDefault)
            userDailyBudgetPassedOver = dailyBudgetDefault
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addMoneyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addMoney", sender: self)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "addMoney"{
            let addMoneyVC = segue.destination as! AddSubtractMoney
            addMoneyVC.callback = { result in
                self.dailySpendingLimitLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", result)
            }
            addMoneyVC.callbackForSavings = { result in
                 self.dailySavingsNumberLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", self.userDailySavingsPassedOver! - result)

            }
            addMoneyVC.dailyBudgetPassedThrough = userDailyBudgetPassedOver!    
        }

    }
}

class AddSubtractMoney: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!

    var runningNumber = ""
    var finalNumberPassedOver : Double?
    var amountPassedBackToUserInfo : Double = 0.0
    var dailyBudgetPassedThrough : Double = 0.0
    var runningCountPassedBack : Double = 0.0

    var callback : ((Double)->())?
    var callbackForSavings : ((Double)->())?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        outputLabel.text = "0"
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        runningNumber += "\(sender.tag)"
        outputLabel.text = runningNumber
    }

    @IBAction func submitNewInfo(_ sender: UIButton) {
        AddSubtractMoneyController.addToMoneySpentArray(amountISpent: outputLabel.text!)
        sendBackUpdatedNumber()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func allClearedPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        runningNumber = ""
        outputLabel.text = "0"
    }

    func sendBackUpdatedNumber(){
        amountPassedBackToUserInfo = dailyBudgetPassedThrough - Double(runningNumber)!
        print(amountPassedBackToUserInfo)
        callback?(amountPassedBackToUserInfo)
        runningCountPassedBack = Double(runningNumber)!
        callbackForSavings?(runningCountPassedBack)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the following logic. The place where you are getting the amount to be subtracted from the AddSubtractMoneyVC place the new amount that is the (daily budget - daily expense) to a new userdefault. To distinguish between the callback have a boolean set when the callback is received from the AddSubtractMoneyVC. With this boolean we can have a distinguish between the first entered amount and the modified amount.

Comment: Also make use of the SwiftLint to lint your swift code as it seems to be very unorganised. For example:
var finalNumberPassedOver : Double?
var amountPassedBackToUserInfo : Double = 0.0
Follow the same pattern use either:
var finalNumberPassedOver : Double?
var amountPassedBackToUserInfo :  Double?
https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint

Comment: @FionaShoff thank you for the feedback and advice. I am going to implement that now. Also, thank you for the swiftLint tip! I was re tracing my steps to find a bug so I changed a few properties to decipher where I was getting incorrect amounts from, and never changed back. But I will definitely make it a point to organize my code as clean as possible at all time, thank you. I’ll reply done when I finish implementing your strategy.